# Side-by-Side Boxplots in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have this dataframe:

[image: this]

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
                            [4, 7, 10], [5, 8, 11]
                            ]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

How would I create side by side boxplots in Altair for each variable?

Answer (score 3):

You have wide-form data, while Altair works best with long-form data. For a discussion of this, see [Long-Form vs. Wide-Form Data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) in the Altair docs.

You can reshape your data either in pandas using the [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function (as demonstrated in [@chthonicdaemon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057747/2937831)), or you can use Altair's [Fold Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html) to reshape the data within your chart specification.

Here is an example of the transform-based approach:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
                            [4, 7, 10], [5, 8, 11]
                            ]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

alt.Chart(df).transform_fold(
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    as_=['key', 'value']
).mark_boxplot().encode(
    x='key:N',
    y='value:Q'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The key is understanding that altair expects the data in narrow format, which we can do with `.melt()`:

```
import altair as alt

alt.Chart(df.melt()).mark_boxplot().encode(
    x='variable',
    y='value'
)
```

Result:

[image: boxplots]